# Generate Matlab Plot Code from Figure Editor

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, color-mapping, spectrogram

I'm plotting a spectrogram in Matlab and have been editing the axis properties, colormap, and a few other things manually by hand in the Figures editor ("Edit > Colormap or Axis Properties...").

Is there a way to generate/view the code that is creating the plots from the Figure Editor? I could/should dig around some more to see what the calls are to show/fix the color bar and the color map, but it would be really nice to just see the code exactly how I've edited it through the Figure editor. Is this possible?

Comment: There are many commands you can use to edit a figure.  Can you give us a list of things that you're modifying to the figure?  That way, we / I can provide you a command for each thing you're trying to edit.

Comment: It _is_ easier to use figure editor to make the plot look as expected. http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/04/19/reproducing-figures/ Here is a possible way to generate code from the plot. However, the only guaranteed way I can think of to get the exact and most efficient code is by human typing. You can use google (or, of course, stackoverflow) to search for methods for different needs.

Comment: @Yvon - Ah yes.  I forgot that you can generate a M-File for a figure.  Nicely done!

Comment: Instead of "playing around" in the figure editor, you could also `inspect(your_figure_handle)` or `inspect(your_axes_handle)` to get a list of all properties. You can edit them and you directly see what have changed. And later on you can just do the same by `set(handle,property,newValue)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the editing menu you can show the code-changes simply by **right-clicking into the figure** and choosing "Show-M-Code"

[image]

Comment: Genius! I swear I thought I looked under all the menus I could find.... Thanks a ton, this is just what I was looking for!!